# Lighthouse GraphQL data ownership via user_id

Tags: php, graphql, lumen, laravel-lighthouse

I have an application that allows for multiple users. Each user is completely isolated from each other; this means that everything that's not a user in the database has a `user_id` column and only the logged-in user is allowed to view, update, or delete them. In addition, users cannot create rows with someone else's user_id.

Is there a built-in way to solve this with Lumen/Lighthouse? Here's what I've done, and it works, but I'm wondering if I've re-invented the wheel:

1. Every Model has a `user` relationship, like this:

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

2. I've added a `HasOwnerTrait` to these models, with the following contents:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function (Model $model) {
        $model->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    });

    static::saving(function (Model $model) {
        if ($model->user_id !== Auth::user()->id) {
            $exception = new ModelNotFoundException();
            $exception->setModel(self::class, $model->id);
            throw $exception;
        }
    });

    static::deleting(function (Model $model) {
        if ($model->user_id !== Auth::user()->id) {
            $exception = new ModelNotFoundException();
            $exception->setModel(self::class, $model->id);
            throw $exception;
        }
    });
}

public function scopeIsOwner($query)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

3. And finally, in my schema definition:

```
type Query {
    recipes: [Recipe!]! @all(scopes: ["isOwner"])
}

type Mutation {
    createRecipe(input: CreateRecipeInput! @spread): Recipe @create
    updateRecipe(id: ID!, input: UpdateRecipeInput! @spread): Recipe @update
    deleteRecipe(id: ID!): Recipe @delete
}
```

---

Again, this is working, but does it need to be ad hoc like this, or is there a better way?

Comment: auth middleware ??

Comment: I looked into it but I don’t really know what I would do with it. I’m already using it to authenticate the user

Comment: just check it, probably it can be used instead of traits, with more granular rights control at different levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is fine, it saves writing a whole bunch of boilerplate. A few minor suggestions:

You can make your trait into a bootable trait that is automatically called by the framework by renaming the `boot` method to `bootHasOwnerTrait`.

Maybe consider making the `isOwner` scope active by default. In Laravel, this is confusingly called a *global scope*. That allows you to omit naming the scope explicitly, although you can still omit it if you have some queries where it should not apply, e.g. statistics.

Comment: This is great advice. If I made the scope global, any idea how I would omit it later on if I needed to?

Comment: `MyModel::withoutGlobalScope('isOwner')`